# UIPageViewController and off screen orientation changes

Tags: ios, orientation, uipageviewcontroller

My app is a tab bar application running on iPad.

One of the tabs contains a UIPageViewController, which I implemented pretty much as per the tutorial here: [Implementing UIPageViewController programmatically – without storyboarding](http://www.ioslearner.com/implementing-uipageviewcontroller-programatically-without-storyboarding/).

Everything works great, including rotation. However there is a problem - if I go to the tab containing the page view controller, then navigate to a different tab and change the orientation. Then navigation *back* to the tab containing the page view controller, it is now displayed incorrectly.

Rotating the device again, with the page view controller visible, fixes things.

I guess this is because

```
pageViewController:spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:
```

is not called while that tab is not visible. Any ideas on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by re-initialising the UIPageViewController inside viewWillAppear:animated. Not ideal, but it works...

Comment: How to re-initialise it ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and ended up doing the same workaround. When I was done I didn't really hate it though, because it allowed me to free-up the UIPageViewController and all of it's child UIPageViewControllers and all of their resources when the user wasn't actively using the tab.